# Is there a way to add an intersection to a set in python?

Tags: python, set, intersection, frozenset

For example:

```
A=set(frozenset[x,x+1]for x in range (10))
B=set()
C=set()
Result=set()
for B in A:
      for C in A:
            if B!=C:
                 Result.add(frozenset(B.intersection(C)))
```

#Error: descriptor 'intersection' for 'frozenset' objects doesn't apply to a 'types.GenericAlias' object

Comment: `frozenset[x,x+1]` just doesn't mean what you think it means.

Answer (score 3):

You can just use the .intersection() method:

```py
x = {"apple", "banana", "cherry"}
y = {"google", "microsoft", "apple"}

z = x.intersection(y)

print(z)
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

Thank you  @"user2357112 supports Monica",
that was infact the Problem...
if I interchange it with

```
frozenset({x,x+1})
```

it totally works.